# Xamarin.Android deploy to device android 4.1 failed

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to deploy xamarin.Android app to a Sony Xperia Z1 device with an old android version 4.1. By the way i have turned the device to development mode and turned on USB debugging

The visual studio is giving me this error as shown is the screen shot below. Any ideas what can I do????

When I tried to deploy the app to an other android device which has an android version 8.1 works fine.

**Screen shot of the error**

[image: strong text]

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       ADB0010: Unexpected install output: Error: Unknown option: -d
usage: pm list packages [-f] [-d] [-e] [-s] [-3] [-i] [-u] [FILTER]
       pm list permission-groups
       pm list permissions [-g] [-f] [-d] [-u] [GROUP]
       pm list instrumentation [-f] [TARGET-PACKAGE]
       pm list features
       pm list libraries
       pm path PACKAGE
       pm install [-l] [-r] [-t] [-i INSTALLER_PACKAGE_NAME] [-s] [-f]
                  [--algo <algorithm name> --key <key-in-hex> --iv <IV-in-hex>] PATH
       pm uninstall [-k] PACKAGE
       pm clear PACKAGE
       pm enable PACKAGE_OR_COMPONENT
       pm disable PACKAGE_OR_COMPONENT
       pm disable-user PACKAGE_OR_COMPONENT
       pm grant PACKAGE PERMISSION
       pm revoke PACKAGE PERMISSION
       pm set-install-location [0/auto] [1/internal] [2/external]
       pm get-install-location
       pm set-permission-enforced PERMISSION [true|false]

pm list packages: prints all packages, optionally only
  those whose package name contains the text in FILTER.  Options:
    -f: see their associated file.
    -d: filter to only show disbled packages.
    -e: filter to only show enabled packages.
    -s: filter to only show system packages.
    -3: filter to only show third party packages.
    -i: see the installer for the packages.
    -u: also include uninstalled packages.

pm list permission-groups: prints all known permission groups.

pm list permissions: prints all known permissions, optionally only
  those in GROUP.  Options:
    -g: organize by group.
    -f: print all information.
    -s: short summary.
    -d: only list dangerous permissions.
    -u: list only the permissions users will see.

pm list instrumentation: use to list all test packages; optionally
  supply <TARGET-PACKAGE> to list the test packages for a particular
  application.  Options:
    -f: list the .apk file for the test package.

pm list features: prints all features of the system.

pm path: print the path to the .apk of the given PACKAGE.

pm install: installs a package to the system.  Options:
    -l: install the package with FORWARD_LOCK.
    -r: reinstall an exisiting app, keeping its data.
    -t: allow test .apks to be installed.
    -i: specify the installer package name.
    -s: install package on sdcard.
    -f: install package on internal flash.

pm uninstall: removes a package from the system. Options:
    -k: keep the data and cache directories around after package removal.

pm clear: deletes all data associated with a package.

pm enable, disable, disable-user: these commands change the enabled state
  of a given package or component (written as "package/class").

pm grant, revoke: these commands either grant or revoke permissions
  to applications.  Only optional permissions the application has
  declared can be granted or revoked.

pm get-install-location: returns the current install location.
    0 [auto]: Let system decide the best location
    1 [internal]: Install on internal device storage
    2 [external]: Install on external media

pm set-install-location: changes the default install location.
  NOTE: this is only intended for debugging; using this can cause
  applications to break and other undersireable behavior.
    0 [auto]: Let system decide the best location
    1 [internal]: Install on internal device storage
    2 [external]: Install on external media

   at Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbOutputParsing.CheckInstallSuccess(String output, String packageName) in E:\A\_work\293\s\External\androidtools\Mono.AndroidTools\Internal\AdbOutputParsing.cs:line 345
   at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice.<>c__DisplayClass95_0.<InstallPackage>b__0(Task`1 t) in E:\A\_work\293\s\External\androidtools\Mono.AndroidTools\AndroidDevice.cs:line 753
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()         0


Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       ADB0000:  Deployment failed
Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException: Unexpected install output: Error: Unknown option: -d
usage: pm list packages [-f] [-d] [-e] [-s] [-3] [-i] [-u] [FILTER]
       pm list permission-groups
       pm list permissions [-g] [-f] [-d] [-u] [GROUP]
       pm list instrumentation [-f] [TARGET-PACKAGE]
       pm list features
       pm list libraries
       pm path PACKAGE
       pm install [-l] [-r] [-t] [-i INSTALLER_PACKAGE_NAME] [-s] [-f]
                  [--algo <algorithm name> --key <key-in-hex> --iv <IV-in-hex>] PATH
       pm uninstall [-k] PACKAGE
       pm clear PACKAGE
       pm enable PACKAGE_OR_COMPONENT
       pm disable PACKAGE_OR_COMPONENT
       pm disable-user PACKAGE_OR_COMPONENT
       pm grant PACKAGE PERMISSION
       pm revoke PACKAGE PERMISSION
       pm set-install-location [0/auto] [1/internal] [2/external]
       pm get-install-location
       pm set-permission-enforced PERMISSION [true|false]

pm list packages: prints all packages, optionally only
  those whose package name contains the text in FILTER.  Options:
    -f: see their associated file.
    -d: filter to only show disbled packages.
    -e: filter to only show enabled packages.
    -s: filter to only show system packages.
    -3: filter to only show third party packages.
    -i: see the installer for the packages.
    -u: also include uninstalled packages.

pm list permission-groups: prints all known permission groups.

pm list permissions: prints all known permissions, optionally only
  those in GROUP.  Options:
    -g: organize by group.
    -f: print all information.
    -s: short summary.
    -d: only list dangerous permissions.
    -u: list only the permissions users will see.

pm list instrumentation: use to list all test packages; optionally
  supply <TARGET-PACKAGE> to list the test packages for a particular
  application.  Options:
    -f: list the .apk file for the test package.

pm list features: prints all features of the system.

pm path: print the path to the .apk of the given PACKAGE.

pm install: installs a package to the system.  Options:
    -l: install the package with FORWARD_LOCK.
    -r: reinstall an exisiting app, keeping its data.
    -t: allow test .apks to be installed.
    -i: specify the installer package name.
    -s: install package on sdcard.
    -f: install package on internal flash.

pm uninstall: removes a package from the system. Options:
    -k: keep the data and cache directories around after package removal.

pm clear: deletes all data associated with a package.

pm enable, disable, disable-user: these commands change the enabled state
  of a given package or component (written as "package/class").

pm grant, revoke: these commands either grant or revoke permissions
  to applications.  Only optional permissions the application has
  declared can be granted or revoked.

pm get-install-location: returns the current install location.
    0 [auto]: Let system decide the best location
    1 [internal]: Install on internal device storage
    2 [external]: Install on external media

pm set-install-location: changes the default install location.
  NOTE: this is only intended for debugging; using this can cause
  applications to break and other undersireable behavior.
    0 [auto]: Let system decide the best location
    1 [internal]: Install on internal device storage
    2 [external]: Install on external media

   at Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbOutputParsing.CheckInstallSuccess(String output, String packageName) in E:\A\_work\293\s\External\androidtools\Mono.AndroidTools\Internal\AdbOutputParsing.cs:line 345
   at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice.<>c__DisplayClass95_0.<InstallPackage>b__0(Task`1 t) in E:\A\_work\293\s\External\androidtools\Mono.AndroidTools\AndroidDevice.cs:line 753
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()         0
```

Comment: Add the full error of the failing `adb` command to your question (and do not use images for code/errors/exceptions/..., just the formatted text). If needed, turn on MSbuild diagnostic level logging and obtain the full error from that.

Comment: @SushiHangover i have posted the error details

Comment: We fixed this recently, but it will not be available until a future release of Visual Studio. https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/2391

Comment: @JonDouglas Ok Thanks for your reply

Comment: @JonDouglas hi sorry to bother you again i have a question because i'm developing an app with xamarin and cant wait for the next visual studio to come out because i have deadline. About this problem of versions so does it mean if I release the app on google play and who ever download it with android version 4.1 the app wont work?

Comment: @Whiplash No it does not. What it means to you today is that you cannot debug/deploy to < Android 4.4 devices in Visual Studio. I would strongly suggest testing against a higher version for the development purposes until the next version of Visual Studio 15.9. If you release to the Google Play Store, there should not be an issue with installing it on < Android 4.4 devices. Therefore you should be fine.